# Data transformation via solr schema file

Tags: solr

I am wondering if the following can be achieved using the solr schema file?

I have a multivalued field being imported that has data like

- Products
- Products/Computers
- Products/Computers/Laptop
- Products/Computers/Laptops/Webcams

Now, what I would like to do is add a value to the start of each value when being imported example like a depth indicator....

- C0/Products
- C1/Products/Computers
- C2/Products/Computers/Laptops
- C3/Products/Computers/Laptops/Webcams

Anyone know if this is possible or will I best be looking at doing the transformation at my datasource before the import?

Thanks in advance any help or pointers would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can achieve that with a [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer), by counting the number of separators (/) and prepending the CNumber to the value.

But if you are preprocessing the data to index it, then I would take do that in there, if you avoid the ScriptTransformer indexing will be faster and you would have less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method if you are on Solr 4 is to use the ScriptUpdateProcessor to modify the data before you do the tokenizing.  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor

With the ScriptUpdateProcessor, you don't have to write Java, you can use JavaScript, or other scripting languages like Python or Ruby.

Comment: @Eric, Could you elaborate a little more about the feature..? There are no good examples too..

Comment: @Kathick  It's all brand new, just committed.  The link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor has the example, just check out TRUNK to play with it.   It's like any other updateprocessor, but instead of writing code in Java to do the logic, you can use a scripting langugage.  JS is out of the box supported.